# Overflow-x on Android 4.2.2 Stock browser

Tags: android, html, css, overflow, android-browser

I'm experiencing a strange problem on the stock browser on an HTC One X running Android 4.2.2.

I have a container div with overflow-x set to hidden and overflow-y set to auto, it has fixed width and height dimensions. The child content has width and height that exceeds its parent. The idea is that you should be able to scroll vertically but not horizontally. Every browser that i've seen behaves correctly and I get the desired effect. However, on this Android Stock browser I am able to scroll horizontally AND vertically freely, which is not what I want as the overflow-x: hidden is supposed to prevent horizontal scrolling.

I've created a codepen to demo the basic problem:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXjZKR

Code here too:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1' />
    <style>


    .container{
        width: 300px;
        height: 500px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;

    }
    ul.pages {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    li {
        width: 300px;
        line-height: 500px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        vertical-align: top;
        text-align: left;
        white-space: normal;
        height: auto;
    }
    li.one {
        background-color: red;
    }
    li.two {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    li.three {
        background-color: green;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" id="container">
        <ul class="pages">
            <li class="one">Hello<br /><br /></li>
            <li class="two">good</li>
            <li class="three">bye</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have also noticed that if I shorten the height of the child content to be less than the container, then the content no longer scrolls horizontally either. Unfortunately the content will always be taller than the container.

Have spent hours trying to work out why this is happening and, more importantly, looking for a workaround but have had no luck so far.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the `<li>` elements are set to `display: inline-block` in order to hide them horizontally. If so, your issue is that the `.container` element is not the parent of the `<li>`.

The actual parent - the `ul.pages` - is defaulting to `overflow: auto` in this browser for some reason. Set that to `overflow-x: hidden` and you should be alright.

Comment: You're right in that the `li` elements are `display: inline-block` to hide them horizontally. To give a bit more context, each `li` is a page of a book and the `.container` div is a 'viewport' for the current visible page. I dont want users to scroll into the next page. This is done instead via a button click. When clicked the `ul.pages` element is shifted along by changing it's `left` property in the css, so that the next li element is visible. Your solution to set overflow-x: hidden on `ul.pages` cuts off the remaining li's, so they wont actually be visible on the button click.